# Bootstrap 4 beta ( latest version ) Change colors of striped table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a striped table coded as follows:

```
<table class="table-sm table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                   ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am using the latest Bootstrap 4 beta version.  I want to change the alternating colors that Bootstrap uses to "stripe" the rows.  I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation.  As per a four year old post here on Stack Overflow, I could just add my own css file.  However, I'd like, if it's possible, to do this just using bootstrap classes.

Thanks for your help,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the element on the demo page [Bootstrap v4 tables](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) you will see that they are targeting the Bootstrap `.table-striped` class. Specifically, the odd rows. Here's a demo that should help [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbuchanan/k6mukehr/).

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to put `table` class to your element  write like this `<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped">`  should work, or maybe you have not included `bootstrap CSS` Properly