# bootstrap change striped table color, while from <tr>, <td> is not the case

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, html-table, twitter-bootstrap-3

I follow the bootstrap's table temple did print out the table I want, but how to change color though

most of the result I found is input color in `<tr class="table-primary">...</tr>` , but I don't get `<tr> , <td>` in my html

- [my original website pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW6kN.png)
- [demo colorful pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYqpV.png) and [demo bootstrap's link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)

**Q: can I make it colorful, or also same category data with same color, such as 3 "status" is alarm, that three rows are red, and 7   "status" normal are green**

- original code

```
var Selected_add_edit_api; 

    $(document).ready(function () {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token")

      console.log("GET TOKEN", getToken)

      var table = $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.01.10:8000/api/all",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA", response.users);
            return response.users
          }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: null,
            title: "ACTION",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="Edit_Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever=" ">Edit</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-btn" id="Delete_Data" data-id="' + row.userid + '">Delete</button>';
            }
          },
        
          
          { data: "userid", title: "Login ID" },
          { data: "name", title: "Name" },
          { data: "acc_type", title: "Account Type" },
          { data: "created_at", title: "Created Time" }
        ]
      });


      table.draw()
```

in case the code if needed, *I extract data from api feedback, and form the table base on it, therefore, not sure where can I change table style to more colorful*

I just learn js but I want to present more pretty demo while presenting tomorrow

(ps. I did have seen [similar case discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247284/bootstrap-4-beta-latest-version-change-colors-of-striped-table)) but they also fix from `<tr>` not really fit my case

I'm presenting tomorrow, but I do wanna make it prettier